# What I need to start writing angular SSR?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I have started to build a website with angular and I need to use server side rendering, I have seen a lot of videos on (youtube.com) and search more for it without any actual result.
can you help me to learn the simple main steps to start with SSR?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hard question to fully answer.

I'd start of reading and following: https://angular.io/guide/universal

Here for converting an app (I'd suggest following it): https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

A full project which can be used to start from https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Then, its just playing and using it! Best of luck :)